# Would data transfer between USB3 drives connected to a USB3 hub be faster even if the host computer is only USB2

Tags: hard-drive, usb, backup

I know transfer to the computer will be slower but but how about just moving the data between two drives when on the same 3.0 hub?

I would like to know for the hopeful speed increase on transferring my incremental off site backups from a transfer drive into the correct locations on the permanent ones.

I just don't know enough on the transfer to know if the data gets sent directly between the two or if it gets pulled to the computer over the slower 2.0 port then sent to the other drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be at USB v2 speeds (up to 480Mbps).

The USB host controller is doing the transfer and it runs at USB v2 speeds.  All devices attached to that controller move data through that controller.

Comment: Also, don't forget it's 480Mbps both ways, so 240Mbps for downloading, 240Mbps uploading, along the link. And that's also split up between other USB devices plugged in on the same controller usually

Comment: its possible that it may be *slightly* faster, since the USB chips on the v3 devices may handle data faster.  If its true, it probably wouldnt even be noticeable.

Comment: @CanadianLuke true.  If there are two host controllers, he could split it across them.  That would be faster.